# Measure preserving system with only trivial eigenfunctions

Tags: ergodic-theory

I want to show that if $(X,\mathcal{X}, \mu, S)$ is a measure preserving system, then $S$ has no non-trivial eigenfunctions if and only if the spectral measures corresponding to all
non-constant functions $f \in L^2(\mu)$ have no point masses. (Although I am not absolutely certain it is true!)

What I have done is show that for any $f \in L^2(\mu)$ with spectral measure $\sigma_f$, we have that
\begin{equation}
\sigma_f(\{a\})=0 \iff f \perp E_a := \{g \in L^2(\mu): Sg=e^{2\pi ia}g \}
\end{equation}
which is a closed subspace of $L^2(\mu)$, for any $a \in [0,1)$. From this the sufficiency of my claim follows, because an eigenfunction belongs to some $E_a$, so that the respective spectral measure would have a point mass on $a$. To prove the other direction, I assume that  $S$ has only trivial eigenfunctions (that is, constant functions), but that there exists $f \in L^2(\mu)$ and $a \in [0,1)$, such that $\sigma_f(\{a\})>0$. For $a\neq0$ the equivalency above implies that $f$ is not orthogonal to $E_a$ and so $\mathbb{E}(f|E_a)$ is a non-trivial eigenfunction of $S$. My problem is that if $\sigma_f(\{0\})>0$, it seems like I could have $\mathbb{E}(f|E_0)$ being a constant function. So, how to proceed?

Comment: The details aren't quite right here. You need the transformation to be ergodic, not just measure preserving, or else there will be non-constant invariant functions. Also, $f$ needs to be orthogonal to constants, not just non-constant. With these adjustments, the statement works (in fact, it is immediate, if you are familiar with the fact that the eigenvalues of a normal operator are the point masses of its spectral measures).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I have actually shown that the spectrum of $S$ is trivial, meaning that $S$ has no eigenfunctions which are not $S$-invariant, if and only if the spectral measures corresponding to all functions $f \in L^2(\mu)$, which are 
orthogonal to the subspace of $S$-invariant functions, have no point masses. If I also assume ergodicity, then I can enlarge my set to be the functions which are orthogonal to constants.